# Toolbar Spinner Dropdown inflating issue

Tags: android, android-layout, android-spinner

I am passing my custom layout in constructor of `ArrayAdapter<String>`:

```
private static class ActionSpinnerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

   public ActionSpinnerAdapter(final Context context) {
        super(context,
                R.layout.action_spinner_text, //This is my own layout
                //R.id.action_text,
                Lists.newArrayList(ACTION_REPLY, ACTION_REPLY_ALL, ACTION_FORWARD));
```

**action_spinner_text.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/action_text"
  android:layout_width="90dp"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:paddingBottom="10dp"
  android:paddingLeft="8dip"
  android:paddingStart="8dp"
  android:paddingTop="10dp"
  android:paddingRight="8dp"
  android:paddingEnd="8dp"
  android:text="@string/reply_all_action"
  android:textSize="18sp" />
```

And these are my `getView()` and `getDropDownView()` methods:

```
@Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View result = super.getDropDownView(position, convertView, parent);
        result.setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
        TextView textView = ((TextView) result.findViewById(R.id.action_text));
        textView.setTextColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.dark_grey));
        textView.setText(getDisplayValue(position));
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View result = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        TextView textView = ((TextView) result.findViewById(R.id.action_text));
        textView.setTextColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
        textView.setText(getDisplayValue(position));
        return result;
    }
```

But When I click on DropDown from Toolbar it shows text values with black background on right side.

[image]

**What went wrong?**

Comment: give background color white to textview...

Comment: Still it doesn't help. I have tried it before posting. What it does is, it also shows on toolbar with white background.

Comment: Same issue with different sizes of black backgrounds

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem, and it seems like there's a bug in Pre-Lollipop devices when you specify a size in the dropdown view that is not "match_parent" on "android:layout_width", basically all you need to do is 
this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/action_text"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:paddingBottom="10dp"
  android:paddingLeft="8dip"
  android:paddingStart="8dp"
  android:paddingTop="10dp"
  android:paddingRight="8dp"
  android:paddingEnd="8dp"
  android:text="@string/reply_all_action"
  android:textSize="18sp" />
```

Hope it Helps!